# GPUImage crash ('over release framebuffer') when using Blend Filter

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm getting a headache because of the crash I experience when trying to apply Blend filter to an image and displaying it.
What I want to do is simply put an overlay image onto another image.

Here's my code:

```
- (GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *)myFilter
{
    GPUImageFilterGroup *filtersGroup = [GPUImageFilterGroup new];

    // Saturation
    GPUImageSaturationFilter *saturationFilter = [GPUImageSaturationFilter new];
    saturationFilter.saturation = 0.0;
    [filtersGroup addFilter:saturationFilter];

    // Noise
    UIImage *noiseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noise.png"];
    GPUImagePicture *noisePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:noiseImage];
    GPUImageAddBlendFilter *blend = [GPUImageAddBlendFilter new];
    [blend useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [filtersGroup addFilter:blend];
    [noisePicture addTarget:blend atTextureLocation:1];
    [noisePicture processImage];

    [saturationFilter addTarget:blend];

    filtersGroup.initialFilters = @[saturationFilter];
    filtersGroup.terminalFilter = blend;

    return filtersGroup;
}
```

---

---

```
    // Applying filter
    GPUImageOutput <GPUImageInput> *effect = [self myFilter];
    self._photoHandle = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:staticImage];
    [self._photoHandle addTarget:effect];
    [effect addTarget:self.targetPreviewView];
    [self._photoHandle processImage]; // Crash
```

When I try to run it, app crashes and I get this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to overrelease a
>   framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture
>   before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?'

I do call 'useNextFrameForImageCapture' on blend filter so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to call `useNextFrameForImageCapture` at all, do you ever call `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer`?

Comment: No, I don't call '-imageFromCurrentFramebuffer'. I guess it's called somewhere underneath when '-processImage' is called?

Comment: No its not, try removing your call to `useNextFrameForImageCapture` and see if it works

Comment: nope, still same thing :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argh, I found out what caused the crash.

Notice that I don't keep any strong reference to the noisePicture object.
Replacing:

```
GPUImagePicture *noisePicture
```

with

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImagePicture *noisePicture;
...
self.noisePicture = ...
```

fixed the issue. Thanks for help! :)