# GPUImage mixing image and video getting crash overreleasing a frame buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to mashup videos with videos, or videos with images, or images with images. My code works fine if I'm doing all videos or all images, however when I try and mix images with videos I get a crash on the assertion:

```
Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?
```

I've tried adding `[<some_filter> useNextFrameForImageCapture]` at various points throughout the code, but I can't figure out where I need to add it or if that's even my problem.

My chain is:

```
GPUImagePicture -> any filter     --\ 
                                      > GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter
GPUImageVideoCamera -> any filter --/
```

I've tried simplifying my filter chain for debugging and if I eliminate any middle filters then it works for all combinations of images/videos. But as soon as I add any one of the filters before the blend then it will crash.

Comment: Please take a loot at this [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395093/gpuimage-crash-over-release-framebuffer-when-using-blend-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is an [open bug](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1551) with GPUImage. When mixing a video/camera source with a GPUImagePicture.

I worked around it by adding:

```
GPUImageNormalBlendFilter *blendFilter = [GPUImageNormalBlendFilter new];
[videoCameras[0] addTarget:blendFilter];
[source addTarget:blendFilter];
```

As the first filter in the picture's chain. The video doesn't actually show up and it prevents any crashes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but came up with a workaround AKA "hack."  HTH!!

```
    // next two lines address a bug in the GPUImage reference counting ...
    GPUImageFramebuffer* fb = self.filter.framebufferForOutput;
    [fb disableReferenceCounting];
    [self.filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    // next line was crashing with reference counting ...
    UIImage *retImage = [self.filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Comment: I referred this solution and applied(changed a bit) to my filter graph. `useNextFrameForImageCapture` and `disableReferenceCounting` worked!